# Graphviz cluster alignment

Tags: alignment, cluster-computing, graphviz

My graph has 5 clusters (1 vertical, 4 horizontal),

I want to correct three things here,

1. all horizontal clusters to be on the right side
2. every horizontal cluster to be on the same height with the node connected on the left cluster (no to be shifted above or under)
3. horizontal cluster nodes to order from 1 to 4 as defined in the clusters (not randomly)

I tried grouping and ranking yet couldn't manage to fix it,

[image: Resulting Graph]

```
digraph {
graph[bgcolor = '#FDFDFD']
node[fontname = 'helvetica-bold', width = 1.5, height = 0.5, fontsize=12]
rankdir=TB;

    subgraph cluster_main {
    style=dashed; color= '#625a5a'; 
    label='Steps for \n Scientometric Analysis'
    graph[rankdir=TB]
    node [shape=box, style=filled, color=black, 
          fillcolor = '#91cf60'];
      a[group=g1, label = 'Section 1 \n Descriptive Analysis']
      b[group=g2, label = 'Section 2 \n Intellectual Structure']
      c[label = 'Section 3 \n Historiograph']
      d[group=g3, label = 'Section 4 \n Conceptual structure']
      e[label = 'Section 5 \n Thematic Map']
      f[group=g4, label = 'Section 6 \n Social structure']
      a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f}
  
    subgraph cluster_a {
    color= '#625a5a';
    node [shape=box, style = filled, color=black, 
          fillcolor = '#fee08b'];
      a4[group=g1, label = 'Top manuscripts']
      a3[group=g1, label = 'Most Productive \n Authors']
      a2[group=g1, label = 'Most Cited \n References']
      a1[group=g1, label = 'Main findings']}  
    
    subgraph cluster_b {
    color= '#625a5a';
    node [shape=box, style = filled, color=black, 
          fillcolor = '#fee08b'];
      b4[group=g2, label = 'Source \n coupling analysis']
      b3[group=g2, label = 'Source \n co-citation analysis']
      b2[group=g2, label = 'Article \n coupling analysis']
      b1[group=g2, label = 'Article \n co-citation analysis']}

    subgraph cluster_d {
    color= '#625a5a';
    node [shape=box, style = filled, color=black, 
          fillcolor = '#fee08b'];
     d4[group=g3, label = 'Title & Abstract \n Term Analysis']
     d3[group=g3, 
        label = 'Correspondence Analysis \n for both Keywords']
     d2[group=g3, 
        label = 'Author Keyword \n Co-occurrence & Growth']
     d1[group=g3, 
        label = 'Keyword-Plus \n Co-occurrence & Growth']}

    subgraph cluster_f {
    color= '#625a5a';
    node [shape=box, style = filled, color=black, 
          fillcolor = '#fee08b'];
        f4[group=g4, label = 'Country \n Collaboration Network']
        f3[group=g4, label = 'Edu \n Collaboration Network']
        f2[group=g4, label = 'Author \n Collaboration Network']
        f1[group=g4, label = 'Three Fields \n Plots']}

    a -> {a1 a2 a3 a4}
    b -> {b1 b2 b3 b4}
    d -> {d1 d2 d3 d4}
    f -> {f1 f2 f3 f4}

    edge[style=invis]
      a1 -> b1 -> d1 -> f1
      a2 -> b2 -> d2 -> f2
      a3 -> b3 -> d3 -> f3
      a4 -> b4 -> d4 -> f4

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Clusters are hard to position.  You were pretty close.  I added a cluster around the 4 horizontal clusters to corral them, but that wasn't needed.  And changed the groups.  Look for the word "added" to find the changes.

```
digraph {
  graph[bgcolor = "#FDFDFD"]
  graph [newrank=true] // added
  node[fontname = "helvetica-bold", width = 1.5, height = 0.5, fontsize=12]
  rankdir=TB;

    subgraph cluster_main {
    style=dashed; color= "#625a5a"; 
    label="Steps for \n Scientometric Analysis"
    graph[rankdir=TB]
    node [shape=box, style=filled, color=black, fillcolor = "#91cf60"];
    node [group=vert]  // added
      a[label = "Section 1 \n Descriptive Analysis"]
      b[label = "Section 2 \n Intellectual Structure"]
      c[label = "Section 3 \n Historiograph"]
      d[label = "Section 4 \n Conceptual structure"]
      e[label = "Section 5 \n Thematic Map"]
      f[label = "Section 6 \n Social structure"]
      a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f}

    subgraph cluster_a {
    color= "#625a5a";
    node [shape=box, style = filled, color=black, fillcolor = "#fee08b"];
      a4[label = "Top manuscripts"]
      a3[label = "Most Productive \n Authors"]
      a2[label = "Most Cited \n References"]
      a1[label = "Main findings"]}  
    
    subgraph cluster_b {
    color= "#625a5a";
    node [shape=box, style = filled, color=black, fillcolor = "#fee08b"];
      b4[label = "Source \n coupling analysis"]
      b3[label = "Source \n co-citation analysis"]
      b2[label = "Article \n coupling analysis"]
      b1[label = "Article \n co-citation analysis"]}

    subgraph cluster_d {
    color= "#625a5a";
    node [shape=box, style = filled, color=black, fillcolor = "#fee08b"];
     d4[label = "Title & Abstract \n Term Analysis"]
     d3[label = "Correspondence Analysis \n for both Keywords"]
     d2[label = "Author Keyword \n Co-occurrence & Growth"]
     d1[label = "Keyword-Plus \n Co-occurrence & Growth"]}

    subgraph cluster_f {
    color= "#625a5a";
    node [shape=box, style = filled, color=black, fillcolor = "#fee08b"];
        f4[label = "Country \n Collaboration Network"]
        f3[label = "Edu \n Collaboration Network"]
        f2[label = "Author \n Collaboration Network"]
        f1[label = "Three Fields \n Plots"]
    }

    // added rank=same
    {rank = same a -> {a1 a2 a3 a4} }
    {rank = same b -> {b1 b2 b3 b4} }
    {rank = same d -> {d1 d2 d3 d4} }
    {rank = same f -> {f1 f2 f3 f4} }

    edge[style=invis]
      a1 -> b1 -> d1 -> f1
      a2 -> b2 -> d2 -> f2
      a3 -> b3 -> d3 -> f3
      a4 -> b4 -> d4 -> f4
 }
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: wow, this was exactly what i wanted, thank you very much, much appreciated